# stripping out white space and new line characters from a list entry in python

Tags: python, list

Okay, so I'm working on a program that will do a series of things. First it will read the contents of 2 external files, then it will take each line of said files and convert those lines into a list, and those 2 lists will be combined into one list.

each file is a list of names with an entry number before it, and a new line after it. So each file is a list of between 100 and 200 entries formatted like so:

```
1.  Michael \n
2.  Ben \n
3.  Ken \n
4.  David \n
```

so the program opens the file, then reads each line into a list.

Now here is where my problem is arising. I need to strip out the entry number, the white space and the new line command from each line.

I'm using aline.aplit(' ') for each line so that:

```
1.  Michael \n
```

would become:
    ['1. ','Michael \n']

Okay, so from here I should just need to strip off the '\n' and then append[1] to the list of names from this file.

Well this is where I'm getting an error. Specifically:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "H:/ITP100/assignments/Chapter 7/Names-3.py", line 30, in 
>      entry1 = value_xy.rstrip('\n')
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Here is the full code:

```
Name1 = (input("Enter a name: "))
file_xy = open("BoyNames.txt", "r")
list_xy = []
file_xx = open("GirlNames.txt", "r")
list_xx = []
test_boys =[]
test_girls =[]
entry1 = []
for aline in file_xy:
    value_xy = aline.split(' ')
    entry1 = value_xy.rstrip('\n')
    test_boys.append[1]
    #entry2 = entry1[1].strip()
    list_xy.append(entry1[1])
for aline in file_xx:
    value_xx = aline.split(' ')
    entry_xx1 = value_xx.rstrip('\n')
    test_girls.append(entry_xx1)
    #    entry_xx2 = value_xx[1].lstrip()
    list_xx.append(entry_xx1)
    #print(list_xy)
names = list_xy + list_xx
print("This is the list \'names\'. This is the combined list of all names."+'\n'+str(names))
print("This is the list \'test_boys\'. This is the post-stripping list of boy names."+'\n'+str(test_boys))
print("This is the list \'test_girls\'. This is the post-stripping list of girl names."+'\n'+str(test_girls))
if Name1 in names:
    print(Name1+" is in the list.")
else:
print(Name1+" is not in the list.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strip()` method to get rid of the newline char before splitting.

For example, here is the method to extract the 'name'-part from the following string:

```
s = '1.  Michael \n'

name = s.strip().split()[1]
print(repr(name)) # 'Michael' => no extra spaces
```

---

Let's say, I have the 'names.txt' file with the content:

```
1.  Michael 
2.  Ben 
3.  Ken 
4.  David
```

Then I can get the names from the file in this way:

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    names = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        line_elements = line.strip().split()
        if len(line_elements) > 1: # checking for a line in different format 
            name = line_elements[1]
        names.append(name)

print(names) # ['Michael', 'Ben', 'Ken', 'David']
```

Note that it's preferable to work with files via `with open()` pattern.

Comment: so when you use the 'with open' method you don't need to tell it weather you are opening the file to read or to write to it?

Comment: No, you still can specify `"r"`, `"w"` and other parameters, The feature is that the file will be automatically closed right after `with open` block and therefore you don't need to keep in mind whether your file open or close

Comment: Cool. good to know. 

So now I'm getting an out of range error on this line:
        name = line.strip().split()[1]

Comment: It looks like there is a line which is not in format `x. name \n` - perhaps an empty line. I'll add an edit to the answer

Comment: okay I needed that kick to the head. Yeah it's the source file, not the program. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelCividanes, check the last edit, it should work

Answer (score 1):

```
value_xy = aline.split(' ')
```

above code returns list

```
entry1 = value_xy.rstrip('\n')
```

rstrip()/strip() is applicable for strings so this is causing error in both for loops

so you can iterate and append like following example

```
entry1 = []
for item in value_xy:
    entry1.append(item.rstrip('\n'))
```

I hope it works